# Answering expo build and upload questions automatically

Tags: react-native, expo

I’m trying to create an app generator that creates an expo app and then deploys it to the app store and play store.
I’ve done the generator part, now I have to do the deploy.

My question is, is there a way I can answer to expo-cli interactions in expo build and upload automatically? So I can set them before and then when the user generates the app, I can automatically in an aws instance deploy this app to my app store account?

I know that I can set apple id and password before, as I can set push key and provisioning key. But the first question “? How would you like to upload your credentials? (Use arrow keys)” I just can’t.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it myself with autoexpect!